# CocoaPods Unit Testing Questions

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, cocoapods

I just created a Cocoapods library and want to set up a testing target for that particular library (not the example project).

Here are some questions:

> 1) Is there a default testing target created by default for the library ? If not, why ?

---

> 2) I created a testing target (if my assumption about `1)` is correct that there is no testing target created on library creation), how do I test the library while my main Library Scheme is selected ?

---

> 3) Do I have to add all the source files that need to be tested to my testing target in order to test them ?

Comment: In my answer below, I might be misunderstanding, and your question is more about including your already existing tests on a library you wrote in a pod that you are distributing?  Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Comment: @diatrevolo You must be misunderstanding me. If you look at Alamofire for example (see Github repo) there are tests for the lib in a Tests folder that test the functionality of the library. I just want to test the library from within the pod, I don't think there is a lot to misunderstand about that...

Comment: I guess I'm just not clear if you want to test for example AlamoFire from within your project, or if in this example you are developing a library that you want to deploy with tests...

Comment: If the question is about testing a library or framework in general, you can make a logic test target, which is what I assume you made as stated above, and add all the files you are testing to that target, much like any test target in Xcode.

Comment: I want to test the functionality of my own pod, nothing more. I am not trying to test any other (third party) pods, just the code living inside my own library.

Comment: @diatrevolo It was just unclear to me why there wouldn't be a default test target for the project. Also, I would like to have my Main Target selected and just run CMD + U to unit test it without selecting the scheme for my test target.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT

I misunderstood the question, as is clearly evident from the comments above.  If you have a test target on a framework, and add all the required source to the compile sources step of your build phases, you can test by having your framework target selected and using command-U.  Libraries, on the other hand, will require a separate test target as far as I can tell, but you can add it to the testing phase of your library scheme to test using command-U with your lib target selected (see below).

[image: Add sources to test to the testing target]

[image: Add test target to library scheme test phase]

Comment: I went exactly that route before, and I couldn't make it work with a host application (Logical testing is only supported in the simulator, which makes sense in hindsight). I think this is the correct way to do it even though it's not obvious to me why Cocoapods is not creating a test target in the first place...

Comment: I don't understand what roles the simulator or device play here. I don't understand how one affects the outcome differently than the other. Is there a way to just run the tests without having that alert "Logic testing is not available on this device" pop up ? I.e. set the host application of the test target ? For me it just says "None" all the time

Comment: It seems to me that logic tests do not require an application whatsoever, so why does that box pop up ?

Comment: Yeah, it's mostly semantic...logic testing is meant to be unit testing at its purest, testing as small a piece of logic as possible.  Application testing is meant to live in the scope of an app, where more things can go wrong.  This is why it requires installation of an app, so to speak.  I think adding a dummy app target to your lib to run application tests might work, if this is required by your project, to test lib implementation.  In logic testing, the simulator is simply a place to host the tests, though that doesn't explain why exactly they can't run on device.

Comment: Hmm, it still seems like an overkill operation. Why is it so tedious to run simple unit tests ? I don't get it